# ASP.NET & C# best practices for web-based application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I'd like to start working on a web-based ASP.net application to assist me with some DBA-type tasks.

I am looking for resources, books, tutorials that might show me how to get started in writing a GUI front end for a web-based application using ASP.Net and C#?

I'll need to use whichever option (MVC or Web Forms) that supports:

- dynamic charts, graphs, dash boards and metrics to present data graphically
- dynamic menus and options driven by database to prevent rebuilding every time a new option is added

What are `ASP.NET` & `C#` best practices for web-based application?

Comment: Walking through some introductory ASP.NET MVC tutorials would really be the place to start.

Comment: try.... www.asp.net :) or www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 2):

I think the best place to start is the [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) website.

Answer (score 1):

I found the NerdDinner tutorial pretty helpful to learn ASP.NET MVC, if you're looking for a walkthrough.

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Plural Sight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Find?highlight=true&searchTerm=asp.net%20mvc) has been an excellent resource for me.